# Осинглтовывание класса

Tags: ооп, javascript

Есть набор классов, которые должны быть синглтонами. Можно ли как то унаследовать свойства синглтона (или придать с нуля), чтобы не было такой ерунды как ниже.

```
var ClassOne = function() {
        if(typeof ClassOne.instance === 'object') {
            return ClassOne.instance;
        }

        ClassOne.instance = this;
        return this;
    }

var ClassTwo = function() {
        if(typeof ClassTwo.instance === 'object') {
            return ClassTwo.instance;
        }

        ClassTwo.instance = this;
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если очень просто, то:

```
var Singleton = function () {
    var self = this.constructor;
    return self.__inst || (self.__inst = this);
};

var FooSingleton = function () {
    return Singleton.call(this);
};

console.log(new FooSingleton === new FooSingleton);
```

Или что-то типа этого http://jsfiddle.net/gX6FL/

Comment: Спасибо, чудесный код.